# (Editing a file in the etc repertory ) Cannot edit /etc/sudoers file

Tags: sudo, users, user-management, jenkins

I want nopasswd thing for my `jenkins` user. For that, I have to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file,

But

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/$ sudo vi /etc/sudoers
```

This gives me that this file is readonly and so, I cannot edit this file.

I change to root,

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/$ sudo su
```

And I am getting something like this,

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

and even now I cannot edit the file. It still says this is readonly.

What is wrong ?

How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: got it, I have to use the `sudo visudo` command. But when I log in as root, why this appears ` \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ `

Comment: It is written in the question, `sudo su` from terminal

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? If you tack hardly related questions onto existing questions you're broadening their scope which makes them harder to answer. On top of that it likely invalidates existing answers. I took the liberty to revert the edit that adds the follow-up question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> visudo

This will solve your problem

Comment: Thnku, please check my comment and see if u can help me with my another issue ?

Comment: upvote answers if you could find which is helpful